# OpAmp Buffer (S11 > 1)

Tags: operational-amplifier, vna

I have the following buffer schematic set up:

[image: Gain=-2 Buffer with buffered input]

I am trying to understand why the S11 Parameter goes out of the unity gain circle,
which indicates that the buffer schematic reflects more power than is being input.
The op amp has a PNP type input stage and was operated with an offset bias of 1.5V,
powered by at least 5V - so the inputs were operated within range.

This is the S11 Curve, plotted with qucs using the s4p file of the vector network analyzer,
ranging from 300kHz to 200MHz.

[image: S11 Smith plot - black line indicates Unity circle at 50 Ohms]

This curve was measured with a freshly calibrated Rohde & Schwarz ZVA8.

This VNA has a bias port, providing a DC bias to the output over a bias-tee.

The connections were made with an SMA connector and the board layout has a clear 'direction'
such that input and output lines don't come close to each other.
To me, there are no obvious spots for capacitive coupling of the input and the output line.

Can it be that the high impedance mismatch of the VNA output (50Ohm) and the buffer input caused this?
An experiment showing the contrary is that I have measured an instrumentation amplifier with NPN-type inputs and the curves were fine.

For reference, here is the LTC6226 Datasheet: [LTC6226](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc6226-6227.pdf)

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but two things stand out to me: How confident are you in the quality of the calibration? The other potential thing is it could be that the circuit is unstable in that region, but I suspect not for the input stage of an opamp. My money is "bad calibration."

Comment: Thanks for you guess ! The device is stable - i have looked at the frequency sweep with an oscilloscope. It might be the calibration. The automatic calibration device might have become damaged (not by me :)) - as it does not automatically recognise the Port-2 of the VNA. The damage might go beyond that.